# url.action method not resulting in expected URL output

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, url.action

I was working in a sample MVC project, i have used the below url action method and its not going to the URL as expected.

I have two views in total- named **create** and **index** of **person entity**.
URLs like; app/Person/Create & app/Person/Index.

Here person is controller which is created as class name : PersonController

Now am trying to load Index view back to user, when user clicks on cancel button.

```
    $("#btnCancel").click(function () {
        window.location = '@Url.Action("Index", "Person")';
    });
```

and in person controller i have action defined in name Index.

But the url action returns me the url as :- app/person

Also calling this url action hits the breakpoint at the action **Index** of person coltroller class. And i am **expecting the URLs like app/Person/Create & app/Person/Index**.

Route config.cs - default one which come is mvc projects:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)

    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Can someone help in this issue.?

Comment: What is the expected URL you are hoping to get?

Comment: Show your `RouteConfig.cs` file.

Comment: Index is your default action in route config file most likely. Therefore Index won't show up in the url but should still map correctly.

Comment: I have added the route config code- same as the default codes comes with mvc project.

Comment: Yes it is because of the default route.config config i guess(am not sure). i changed the name of my view. and it is working fine. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After compiling the code,

```
 $("#btnCancel").click(function () {
    window.location = '@Url.Action("Index", "Person")';
});
```

becomes like this:

[image]

But after compiling the code,

```
 $("#btnCancel").click(function () {
    window.location = '@Url.Action("create", "Person")';
});
```

becomes like this:

[image]

Comment: I could understand the explanation but, wats the reason of the person/index page's URL is skipping index from URL. Is it because of route config.

Comment: Yes it is because of the default route.config config i guess. i changed the name of my view. and it is working fine. :-)

Comment: ali, thnQ very much, and could you pls confirm if this is because of this route configuration.?